# Zing chart - how to add more information to the tool tip?

Tags: javascript, charts, zingchart

I am trying Zing Chart and have JS array in this way:

```
"values": [
[1458846060000, 167.272, "Parameter1", "Parameter2", "Parameter3"],
[1458847060000, 150.272, "Parameter1", "Parameter2", "Parameter3"]
]
```

When hover-over specific point - I can show Time, Value and Series in a tooltip but how to show Parameter1,2,3, from the same Array when user hover over specific point in a scatter plot?

thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can use custom tokens, which are defined in the "plot" or "series" object as an attribute or array using the "data" prefix. E.g., "data-fullname" or "data-extracredit".

Here's an example where three custom tokens were created for parameters 1, 2, and 3. To recall them in the tooltips, you would use the tokens %data-parameter1, %data-parameter2, and %data-parameter3. See the demo.

```js
var myConfig = {
  "type":"scatter",
  "title":{
    "text":"Custom Token as Attribute"
  },
  "plot":{
    "tooltip":{
      "text":"%kv, %v, %data-parameter1, %data-parameter2, %data-parameter3."
    }
  },
  "scale-x":{
    "transform":{
      "type":"date",
      "all":"%g:%i %A"
    }
  },
  "scale-y":{
 
  },
  "series":[
    {
      "values": [
        [1458846060000, 167.272],
        [1458847060000, 150.272],
        [1458848060000, 134.311]
      ],
      "data-parameter1":"Parameter1",
      "data-parameter2":"Paremeter2",
      "data-parameter3":"Parameter3"
    }
  ]  
};
 
zingchart.render({ 
 id : 'myChart', 
 data : myConfig, 
 height: 400, 
 width: 600 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
  <script> zingchart.MODULESDIR = "https://cdn.zingchart.com/modules/";
  ZC.LICENSE = ["569d52cefae586f634c54f86dc99e6a9","ee6b7db5b51705a13dc2339db3edaf6d"];</script></head>
 <body>
  <div id='myChart'></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

http://demos.zingchart.com/view/78P4SI51

Alternatively, you can use an array to assign text for each individual node. See the demo.

```js
var myConfig = {
  "type":"scatter",
  "title":{
    "text":"Custom Token as Array"
  },
  "plot":{
    "tooltip":{
      "text":"%kv, %v, %data-parameter1, %data-parameter2, %data-parameter3."
    }
  },
  "scale-x":{
    "transform":{
      "type":"date",
      "all":"%g:%i %A"
    }
  },
  "scale-y":{
 
  },
  "series":[
    {
      "values": [
        [1458846060000, 167.272],
        [1458847060000, 150.272],
        [1458848060000, 134.311]
      ],
      "data-parameter1":["Parameter1a","Parameter1b","Parameter1c"],
      "data-parameter2":["Paremeter2a","Parameter2b","Parameter2c"],
      "data-parameter3":["Parameter3a","Parameter3b","Parameter3c"]
    }
  ]  
};
 
zingchart.render({ 
 id : 'myChart', 
 data : myConfig, 
 height: 400, 
 width: 600 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
  <script> zingchart.MODULESDIR = "https://cdn.zingchart.com/modules/";
  ZC.LICENSE = ["569d52cefae586f634c54f86dc99e6a9","ee6b7db5b51705a13dc2339db3edaf6d"];</script></head>
 <body>
  <div id='myChart'></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

http://demos.zingchart.com/view/GSGWW4YO

Let me know if that helps! I'm on the ZingChart team and happy to answer further questions. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same custom tooltip in tree diagram